# How to sent a short message to a smart phone through internet?

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am in a project, from where I am facing a problem, because the user wants to sent a short message to his clients smart phone about their UserID and Password by using internet.

Comment: Please tell me the country where you want to send message and do you want to use a paid service or a free service (that will write its own add in sms).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send email then its easily available but for text messages you have to get an API for sms sending. In many countries sms sending api's are available for free. A paid service is telephoney.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these phones are connected to a wireless provider, many phones can receive texts through email.

Here is AT&T's page on how to send these messages [[Link]](http://www.att.com/esupport/article.jsp?sid=KB63037&cv=820#fbid=oFa-lyBYMuM)

There is also the issue of security though. I have no clue whether or not this would be a safe way to transmit someones ID and Password information.